# Was Legend inspired by North and South Korea?

Tags: inspiration, legend

In the *[Legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Lu_novel))* series by Marie Lu, there are two countries side-by-side in what used to be the U.S.

One is a hereditary military dictatorship that controls every aspect of its citizens' lives. The other is a state where large corporations wield outsized power. The analogy to North Korea and South Korea (where Samsung accounts for 17% of GDP and wields tremendous political influence) seems obvious.

**Has Marie Lu ever mentioned drawing inspiration from South and North Korea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although not definitively for South Korea.

In an interview with [Marie Lu on bookyurt](http://bookyurt.com/scouting/interviews/marie-lu-talks-legend/), she gives the following responses:

> Byrt: YES. And as for the whole country, you split it east/west?
>
> Marie: I split it down the middle, from the Dakotas through Texas. The west half is called The Republic and the east is called The Colonies – and they hate each other!
>
> Byrt: So were there any historical echoes in this project?
>
> Marie: Definitely. The Eugenics movement that happened in the United States in the early 20th century was a big influence, as well as ancient Sparta and their habit of placing babies that were considered too weak to live out on a hill to die. **North Korea was another big influence.  It’s fascinating to see in real life how quickly a group of people can be brainwashed by their government, if the government has complete control over everything.**

(Emphasis mine)

So while it doesn't mention North AND South Korea, it definitely says that North Korea and the government control was an influence in the book.